# We need a profanity filter

Tags: feature-request, spam, offensive

I searched SE.Meta and was unable to find such question.

Someone just swore at us in a [pretty normal question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/164617/minecraft-pocket-edition-asks-for-additional-payment) as an [answer](https://gyazo.com/ab2d315dd0fbf1fdad354fdc905ca4ad) (warning: profanity, may be NSFW), sure, Arqade (profanity in phrases in games) or some SE (ELU, ELL or Anime.SE maybe?) can sometimes contain profanity as a small parts of question.

I think that a part should be added to the review system that will automatically hide questions/answers with profanity, just like the close vote system, the question/answer will be on hold and will be voted to be shown or be deleted.

Tip, if this gets implemented, u can be typed as \/ or v, and most other can be written as leet (l = 1 etc). Maybe it can be called "suspicious activity", and can be triggered when there is too many number or Unicode characters. (I can write hi as |-| |, |-|I, |-|l, l-li, hî, 1-1i, H1 and many more)

Comment: We have one... they're called flags and mods.

Comment: [Obscenity Filters: Bad Idea, or Incredibly Intercoursing Bad Idea?](http://blog.codinghorror.com/obscenity-filters-bad-idea-or-incredibly-intercoursing-bad-idea/)

Comment: I 4king agree it's tw@y when some sh17 types profanities. but as you can see, it's unlikely we can catch all potentials, people will just work around it. The problems are flagged and resolved pretty quickly, as you have seen in your question/answer already :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There is no need for any extra security.

This is a reason we have flags and moderators to help remove these types of posts. We can simply flag the post as "rude or abusive" and let the moderators deal with what to do with the offensive post. Same goes to comments, which can be flagged for "rude or offensive", which can also be removed due to profanity issues. So I see no need to add a profanity filter at all.

At times, users will cuss for good reason and will hide most of the word to avoid flags like for example, s***. Of course, it depends on the usage of the word though... So really, just flag as rude and abusive/offensive and let the mods decide what to do. There is no need for a filter.