# Could we add a bad word filter for profiles, comments and questions?

Tags: feature-request, reporting

I saw this on a word-search generator and thought it was a good idea. Moderators could add words to a list. When a word is detected that is on the list it will remove it. There can be a request tab for other ranks to request a bad word for moderators to review.

Comment: There are bots built by community members which flag some these things. [SmokeDetector](https://charcoal-se.org/smokey/) which scans questions and answers for abusive and spam content and [Heat Detector](https://stackapps.com/questions/7001/) to flag rude and abusive comments.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

This has been tried. It doesn't work. You're probably thinking of using it for swearwords, but people can never agree on what is or isn't a swearword. (See [We need a profanity filter](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/264098/we-need-a-profanity-filter) and https://blog.codinghorror.com/obscenity-filters-bad-idea-or-incredibly-intercoursing-bad-idea/ )

You actually can't use "problem" in a title, but that doesn't work as well as you think it would. See [The title word filter is one of the worst ideas ever implemented on SO](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/112944/the-title-word-filter-is-one-of-the-worst-ideas-ever-implemented-on-so) for example.

Comment: +1 I've been on the 'net since CLI interfacing into various BBSes and crawling with Telnet.  Nobody's created a good filter yet, and they've been trying since the 80's

Answer (score 11):

The Good Place implemented curse filter.

So we got forks and shirts... and everybody still know it is a curse.

Even if you can define forbidden words, life will find its way around them.

Comment: If people haven't seen The Good Place, do it. It is very much worth a watch.

Comment: E.g. with disguise in l33t code.

Comment: But if they say Fork instead of F*** then no one is swearing right?

Comment: It's a great forking show!

Comment: We could go down the 2000AD/Judge Dredd route and use "stomm", "drokk" and "grud"...!